# Multi tenant Real Life Software Case Study

Tags: cloud, multi-tenant, saas

I am trying to understand multi tenancy. I appreciate if some one help me with  link to a good case study of a real application using muti tenancy. Also wanted to ask if Iphone's Siri would be a multi tenant application to be given as a an example?. I am trying to write a paper here so any references which would help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [this](http://securecloudreview.com/2011/03/what-does-multi-tenant-mean-to-you/) article called **What does Multi-Tenant Mean to You?**

You can see the you could have multi-tenancy in three different contexts:

- **IaaS**: multiple OS instances can run on the same physical hardware through hypervisor technology. Examples: Digital Ocean, Amazon EC2,..
- **PaaS**: platform can isolate code from different apps on the same OS instance. This removes the need to allocate a whole VM per application stack component, improving efficiency. Examples: CloudBees, CloudFoundry,..
- **SaaS**: single runtime stack component instances are shared across multiple customers. Example: Salesforce, Totango,..

You can find [here](http://www.cloudbees.com/company-references.cb) some use cases of companies using multi-tenancy on their applications on a specific PaaS.

I recommend you to test the different contexts to understand better what they mean. There are a lot information on Internet, starting with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

Comment: Sadly your first link is no longer accessible. It constantly times out.